# Wso2am custom sequence - how to log username

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have created a custom sequence in wso2am, in order to convert a rest web service call, to a soap call.

I would like to have the username of the user that makes the actual call, so as to log it,  and use it in the soap body. 
I tried by accessing the tenant.id and tenant domain variables but the are not available. I tried the END_USER_NAME var but that was also null

```
<property name="domain" expression="$ctx:tenant.info.domain" />
<property name="user" expression="substring-before(get-property('END_USER_NAME'), '@')" />
```

Is something like that possible? 
if not, is it possible to deduce the username by means of the authheader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use context property `api.ut.userId` in your sequence.

For example

```
<property name="user" expression="substring-before(get-property('api.ut.userId'), '@')" />
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the username from JWT token. Look [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Passing+Enduser+Attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT) for enabling JWT token. Then extract any user claim youwant. I had explained it at, 
[http://lahiruwrites.blogspot.com/2016/06/access-jwt-token-in-mediator-extension.html](http://lahiruwrites.blogspot.com/).
 Pasting below for your reference(You can see how to get enduser),

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence
    xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Test:v1.0.0--In">
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="--TRACE-- " value="API Mediation Extension"/>
    </log>
    <property name="authheader" expression="get-property('transport','X-JWT-Assertion')"></property>
    <script language="js"> var temp_auth = mc.getProperty('authheader').trim();var val = new Array();val= temp_auth.split("\\."); var auth=val[1];var jsonStr = Packages.java.lang.String(Packages.org.apache.axiom.om.util.Base64.decode(auth), "UTF-8"); var tempStr = new Array();tempStr= jsonStr.split('http://wso2.org/claims/enduser\":\"'); var decoded = new Array();decoded = tempStr[1].split("\"");mc.setProperty("enduser",decoded[0]); </script>
    <log level="custom">
        <property name=" Enduser " expression="get-property('enduser')"/>
    </log>
</sequence>
```

Comment: Havent tried that, but seems legit
In case i will need more than just the username, i will use JWT token.

Thanks

Comment: Lovely little 'gotcha' that I don't think I've seen documented .. if you use a script language (javascript for sure) .. then your max message size is limited to 64k, just something to check